# BULK INSERT clent and session requirements

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bulk-insert

I'm setting up an ETL process using SQL Server 2014 and SSIS. My Bulk Insert Task is utilizing a source file and format file on *ShareA* targeting a DB on *InstanceA*. The package is run via SSA job on *InstanceB*. Both *InstanceA* and *InstanceB* are running the same service account for the Agent. The service account has `bulkadmin` and read/write privs on the target table. It also has appropriate permissions on both the share and folder via NTFS.

When the SSA job runs on *InstanceB*, the job fails on the step with code 5 for Access Denied attempting to access the source file. However, if I run the `BULK INSERT` T-SQL generated by the task in a job on *InstanceA* it succeeds, confirming share/NTFS permissions are OK.

Am I forced to run the SSIS package on my target server *InstanceA* to allow `BULK INSERT` to function or are additional permissions needed in order to run on an alternate server?